# Learning c, my code runs but doesn't displayed print?

Tags: c

Hey i just started learning c, programming.
I can't understand how my code
doesn't work. It runs but it's not printing

where printf(cyn "Would you like to update[y/n]: ");
Doesn't get displayed any ideaas sorry im new to this site.

```
#define red   "\x1B[31m"
#define grn   "\x1B[32m"
#define yel   "\x1B[33m"
#define blu   "\x1B[34m"
#define mag   "\x1B[35m"
#define cyn   "\x1B[36m"
#define wht   "\x1B[37m"
#define reset "\x1B[0m" /* Reset stops after statement 

For example thiscolorisred reset this color is normal */



int main() 
{
        char pwd[30];
        char input[10];
        printf(cyn"Enter Code: " reset);
        scanf("%s", pwd);
        if ( strcmp (pwd, "cycle") == 0)
        {
                system("clear");
                printf("welcome\n",  pwd);
        }
        else 
        {
                printf("Wrong code closing program.");
                return 0;
        }

        printf("Updating system, please wait.\n");
        printf(cyn, "Would you like to update[y/n]: ");
        scanf("%s", input);
        if( strcmp(input, "y") ==0)
        {
                system("sudo apt-get update");
                printf(cyn, "Updated!!!. ");
        }
        else {
                printf(red, "It's recommended that you update");
                return 0;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `cyn`? What is `red`? What is `reset`? What is `printf(cyn"Enter Code: " reset);` supposed to print? What is `printf(cyn, "Would you like to update[y/n]: ");` supposed to print? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and learn how to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: Looks like cyn and red are supposed to be some colouring on the text - presumably some constant string that is a terminal escape code that causes the colouring.  Maybe reset is another constant string that restores the old colouring/code

Comment: sorry i updated wiith what cyn, red, reset is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If cyn and red and reset are constant strings that represent terminal escape strings for colouring the output, then you should not have a comma between those strings and the string you are outputting.

So

```
printf(cyn, "Would you like to update[y/n]: ");
```

should be

```
  printf(cyn "Would you like to update[y/n]: ");
```

The same for the other printf statements that have commas between the terminal escape string and the string to print.

In C, if you put two strings next to each other, the compiler will concatenate them for you.

In other words, the C compiler will treat "my" " string" as "my string".

Comment: @Boxboy306 Now please take some time to think about *why* this fix works, and what made the faulty call wrong.

Comment: @Boxboy306 Alternatively, it could be done like: `printf("%sWould you like to update[y/n]: ", cyn);`

Answer (score 0):

I have an autism, sorry

if you wanna fix it doesn't print you should do it like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define something "test"
int main(){
    printf("left "something" right");
    return 0;
}
```

it will print (left test right)

if it was the number you want to define don't add "